# mouseleave issue once clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a set of jquery functions set to a tags. when I mouseover, the background image changes. when I mouseleave, the image changes back to the original. when I click a link, a popup shows. I click the close function, and everything works turns off correctly. once clicked, when I mouseover the same a tag, the background image changes, but doesn't change back to the original image when I mouseleave. any idea why the mouseleave (after clicking on and off once) does not swap the background back to the original? please let me know if there are questions, I have tried to be descriptive as possible. thanks

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tips-1-link').on({
        mouseover: function() {
            $('.tips-numbers').css('background-image', 'url(0-HTML-Resources/imgs/buying-a-car-2/tips-numbers-hover.png)');
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            $('.tips-numbers').css('background-image', 'url(0-HTML-Resources/imgs/buying-a-car-2/tips-numbers.png)');
        },
        click: function() {

            $('.tip-1-info').css('display', 'block'),
                $('.tips-1-link').off('mouseleave');
        },
    });
    $('.close-info-1').on({
        click: function() {
            $('.tips-numbers').css('background-image', 'url(0-HTML-Resources/imgs/buying-a-car-2/tips-numbers.png)'),
                $('.tip-1-info').css('display', 'none');
        },
    });
```

Comment: Go with event delegation method.

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle of the same

Comment: $('.tips-1-link').off('mouseleave'), remove the mouseleave event, so once you clicked .tips-1-link the mouseleave action is not executed anymore. try removing that line.

Comment: I appologize all, I had a bit of an emergency I had to deal with, taking me this long to get back... I created a fiddle here to illustrate my problem http://jsfiddle.net/skinnyb/0vvk945y/1/
then after clicked and closed, the hover effect turns on, then does not turn off...

Answer (score -1):

Try using [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

```
$( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );
```